# Populating Javabean via openCSV - code explanation

Tags: java, opencsv

I just started with Java and have a lot of missing knowledge, but i need to write a simple class that will convert csv file using openCSV into a JavaBean. I have found some answers to similar quetions here, but none was able to help me. So far, a have come accross this bit of code:

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy(); 
strat.setType(YourOrderBean.class); 
String[] columns = new String[] {"name", "orderNumber", "id"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean 
strat.setColumnMapping(columns); 
CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean(); 
List list = csv.parse(strat, yourReader);
```

which is located on openCSV FAQ site and also in another question here. The problem is I cannot find out specification how the object ColumnPositionMappingStrategy should look like and also what should be passed in strat.setType statement (YourOrder Bean.class). setColumnMapping method is also uncelar to me, but i belive i can figure that one out by myself when I know the rest...

Would anyone be kind enough to explain this bit of code more? The openCSV documentation is very brief for me, as i lack some basic knowlage of Java (coming from PHP, which has major differences)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is defining how to map the `String[]` that is a row of a CSV to the properties of your [`JavaBean`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions).

Lets assume you have a `class` like so:

```
public class JavaBeanExample {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer orderNumber;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(Integer orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
}
```

The key points to note about this class are:

1. Use a public noargs constructor; this is default in Java so no constructor needs to be specified.
2. All properties are private.
3. All properties have getters, i.e. methods called `getXxxx` that return their value.
4. All properties have setter, i.e. methods called `setXxxx` that set their value.

Now; the first method, `setType`, takes the class of your bean. It uses this to create instances via [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html). In this case we would call:

```
strat.setType(JavaBeanExample.class);
```

Next, let us assume that we have a CSV in the following format

> Name,Order Number, Order Id
>   Joe Bloggs, 77777, 00001
>   John Smith, 77778, 00002

So we need to map the first column to our `name` property, the second to our `orderNumber` property and the third to `id`. We use the property names in the bean to tell OpenCSV which setter to use. OpenCSV then uses a [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) to set the property via a correspondingly named setter.

In this case we would call

```
String[] columns = new String[] {"name", "orderNumber", "id"};
strat.setColumnMapping(columns);
```

Now this is all set up we can kick OpenCSV by calling

```
List list = csv.parse(strat, yourReader);
```

This will return a `List` of `JavaBeanExample`, one for each row in your file.

But this is somewhat unpleasant because we have to cast each and every item in the `List`. This is due to the example being somewhat outdated. Here is an example making use of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), this example in written in Java 7.

```
final ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<JavaBeanExample> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
strategy.setType(JavaBeanExample.class);
strategy.setColumnMapping(new String[]{"name", "orderNumber", "id"});
final CsvToBean<JavaBeanExample> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();
final List<JavaBeanExample> beanExamples;
try (final Reader reader = new FileReader("myFile.csv")) {
    beanExamples = csvToBean.parse(strategy, reader);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

The difference here is that we tell the `ColumnPositionMappingStrategy` its generic type using the angle brackets. We also tell the `CsvToBean` its generic type. This means that when we call parse a `List<JavaBeanExample>` is returned; i.e. a `List` knowing its generic type. Now we don't have to cast the individual elements in the `List`.

Comment: the above implementation doesn't skip blank rows

Comment: @shanyangqu why on earth would it? They should not exist in a CSV file. A CSV is a simple, flat, tabular data format. There should no more be blank lines in a CSV file than blank lines in a set of SQL query results.

Comment: @BoristheSpider clam down Boris, I was just saying the fact, whether csv should or penitentially could have blank rows is a different matter.

Comment: @shanyangqu I'm not a clam... You could also have said that this doesn't deal with JSON data and it would be just as helpful a comment. It also doesn't make toast...

Comment: @BoristheSpider : How do we do this when the CSV file is delimited with Tabs?

Comment: @JeraldFDO sorry, but RTFM. Create a [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html) with whatever properties you want and pass that to [CsvToBean.parse](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBean.html).