# ColumnPositionMappingStrategy setType is deprecated

Tags: java, opencsv

### Problem:

I am using `com.opencsv` to parse a CSV file and get back an array of java objects. There is a method called `setType()` that unfortunately is deprecated.
I have not been able to find an equivalent method.

### Dependency:

```
  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

### Spec (Javadoc):

Javadoc for version 3.6 (can't find 3.3):
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.html#setType(java.lang.Class)

### My Code:

```
   private List<importedFromCSV> handleCSV(byte[] bytes,Class clazz) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais));

        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
        strat.setType(clazz);
        //String[] columns = new String[] {"a","b"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
        //do we want csv to include columns or do we hardcode the order?
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(bufferedReader);
        String [] columns;
        if((columns = reader.readNext()) == null) {
            return null;
        }

        strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

        CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
        return csv.parse(strat, bufferedReader);
    }
```

### Related:

Example -  [Populating Javabean via openCSV - code explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259926/populating-javabean-via-opencsv-code-explanation)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455470/what-does-this-mean-this-method-is-deprecated-as-the-user-should-use-the-java-5

Comment: @Denis Gavrus How rude of them.... I guess a link that that page will go in a comment with the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to version 3.6.  It is no longer deprecated.

It was deprecated in the early 3.X releases as we were trying to find a way to work with Generics (so getType would return T instead of what was passed in setType).  When this proved impossible the code was backed out but the deprecation was accidentally left in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, reading the javadoc I noticed something about reading headers. Is there a bettery way than the way I am doing it now to read the fields/columns in an array and then do CsvToBean? Thanks!

Comment: Yes - in the tests in opencsv there are some integration tests.  Look at HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategyUserTest.  Here is the main snippet of the test.           
    private List<MockUserBean> createTestParseResult() throws FileNotFoundException {
       CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(USER_FILE));
        HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MockUserBean> strat = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<MockUserBean>();
       strat.setType(MockUserBean.class);
       CsvToBean<MockUserBean> csv = new CsvToBean<MockUserBean>();
       return csv.parse(strat, reader);
    }